# Why indexOf method is faster than using charAt to traverse a String?

Tags: java, string

I have two answers to a question on leetcode.[Is Subsequence](https://leetcode.com/problems/is-subsequence/)

#### 1

Runtime: 9 ms, faster than 42.67% of Java online submissions for Is Subsequence.
Memory Usage: 42.5 MB, less than 100.00% of Java online submissions for Is Subsequence.

```
class Solution {
    public boolean isSubsequence(String s, String t) {
        int i=0,j=0;
        while(i<s.length()&&j<t.length()){
            if(s.charAt(i)==t.charAt(j))
                ++i;
            ++j;
        }
        return i==s.length();
    }
}
```

#### 2

Runtime: 1 ms, faster than 100.00% of Java online submissions for Is Subsequence.
Memory Usage: 42.5 MB, less than 100.00% of Java online submissions for Is Subsequence.

```
class Solution {
    public boolean isSubsequence(String s, String t) {
        char[] arr = s.toCharArray();
        int index = -1;
        for(int i=0;i<s.length();++i){
            index = t.indexOf(arr[i],index+1);
            if(index<0)
                return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

I think indexOf() is essentially looking for index by traversing String.Inside this indexOf() still need to loop and traverse.

But why the second solution is more efficient than the first？

Comment: You probably need to look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33646781/java-performance-string-indexofchar-vs-string-indexofsingle-string

Comment: have you used jvisualvm to profile the two versions?

Comment: Your current numbers may not be accurate, and you should review how to benchmark a Java application.

Comment: You second variant returns immediately when a character has not been found. You first variant always loops over the entire string, potentially performing unnecessary comparisons. Note that the second variant still is doing unnecessary work by first copying the string into a `char[]` array though.